# UITableViewController over-ride init function not being called when using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

1) I started a new project in xcode using the single view application.

2) I deleted the default view controller and added a new UITableViewController

3) In storyboard, I dragged out a UITableViewController and set it to the one I just created

4) Set the reuse identifier

In my code I tried to override the init method to do some setup. Why is my custom init method not being called? When you are using storyboard, and you drag out a UITableViewController and set it to a custom class, can you not override the initWithStyle: method? When I put the setup in viewDidLoad then it worked.

Here is the code for the view controller:

```
#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"
#import "BNRItemStore.h"

@implementation ItemsViewController

- (id)init
{
    // Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            [[BNRItemStore defaultStore] createItem];
            NSLog(@"Test init");
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{

    NSLog(@"test init style");
    return [self init];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"test tableview rowsinsection");
    return [[[BNRItemStore defaultStore] allItems] count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"test tableview cellforrow");
    // Create an instance of UITableViewCell, with default appearance
    // Check for a reusable cell first, use that if it exists
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"itemsCell"];

    // If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:@"itemsCell"];
    }
    // Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
    // that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
    // will appear in on the tableview
       [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Hello"];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

init  is only called when you using [[class alloc] init]

you can override

```
- (void)awakeFromNib



awakeFromNib
Prepares the receiver for service after it has been loaded from an Interface Builder archive, or nib file.

- (void)awakeFromNib
Discussion
An awakeFromNib message is sent to each object loaded from the archive, but only if it can respond to the message, and only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet instance variables set.
```

Comment: Thank you, using awakeFromNib works to do data setup. Ahh yah so when using storyboard to create view controllers the init method is not called. This is a tricky thing to watch out for.